# TableView found nil in Collectionview cell Swift

Tags: swift, uitableview, uicollectionview, delegates, protocols

Im trying to implement a solution that requires to have a TableView nested in a CollectionView Cell. For some reason then the table view is initialised, it is found as nil. That action is done from within the CollectionView Cell class.

This is the code snippet with the relevant functions:

```
class MNMessgesCollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate{


    @IBOutlet weak var _tableView: UITableView!


    var _messages : [MedNegMessage]?

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()

        // Initialization code
    }

    func setUpViews() {
        _tableView.delegate = self
        _tableView.dataSource = self
         _tableView.register(UINib(nibName: "MessageMNcell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "messageCell")
    }

    func setUpCell(message: [MedNegMessage])
    {
         _messages = message

    }


} 


class  DashboardViewController: UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource{

     func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

          _collectionView.register(MNMessgesCollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "MNmessages")
            guard let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "MNmessages", 
for: indexPath) as? MNMessgesCollectionViewCell 
else { return UICollectionViewCell()}

             cell.setUpViews()
             cell.setUpCell(message: self.messagesMN[indexPath.row])

             return cell

}

}
```

Error is always thrown at  `_tableView.delegate = self`

Unexpectedly found nil while implicitly unwrapping an Optional value

Any advice?

Comment: Make sure the tableView is connected to the outlet in Interface Builder, in whatever nib you have for MNMessgesCollectionViewCell.  Also make sure you are registering MNMessgesCollectionViewCell to the collectionView as a UINib, and not as a class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1)I guess you have just declared the tableView but not wired to the story board.

2)Make sure class all Outlets are correct.